# Powershell: Doubled double quotes in inline expressions

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Please could anyone explain me why the following happens:

```
"Fancy string - Hor""ray"
# outputs correctly (only one double quote): Fancy string - Hor"ray

'Hor"ray'.Replace('"', '""')
# outputs correctly (two double quotes): Hor""ray

"Fancy string - $('Hor"ray'.Replace('"', '"'+'"'))"
#outputs correctly (two double quotes): Hor""ray

"Fancy string - $('Hor"ray'.Replace('"', '""'))"
# outputs INCORRECTLY (only one double quote): Fancy string - Hor"ray
```

In my opinion, developers would intuitively expect, that within "$(inline expressions)" Powershell would treat text as statements and won't interfere with the last argument of `Replace('"', '""')` converting it into `'"'` (unless the statement interpreter decides to do so).

Do I miss something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in how PowerShell parses expandable string literals.

From §2.3.5.2 on string literals in the [PowerShell 3.0 Language Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36389), the *expandable-string-literal* explicitly rejects the `$(` sequence so that *sub-expression* parsing will occur instead.

So it seems reasonable to expect `$('""')` to parse consistently, whether or not it happens to be embedded in a string literal. And clearly sub-expressions are parsed separately, since they support values that would be illegal on their own in an expandable string (e.g. you can write `"$('"')"` or `` "$('`""')" ``, where `" '"' "` or `` " '`""' " `` would fail).

However, comparing the AST from [`[Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.language.parser.parseinput.aspx) for both `$('""')` and `"$('""')"`, we get two different results. Both have a final `StringConstantExpressionAst` element with an `Extent` of `'""'`, but the `Value` for the stand-alone sub-expression is `""` while the `Value` for the embedded sub-expression is `"`.

Comment: Added a bug at [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/903486/doubled-double-quotes-in-inline-expressions-within-expandable-strings). Let's see if they consider it as a bug as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Its because the inline expression is evaluated and its string value is then placed in the string and evaluated.

```
#Breaking "Fancy string - $('Hor"ray'.Replace('"', '""'))" down
#This inline expression is evaluated first
$('Hor"ray'.Replace('"', '""'))
#giving
Hor""ray
#That value is then interpreted as part of the string
"Fancy string - Hor""ray"
#giving
Fancy string - Hor"ray
```

This is exactly what I would expect to see. The inline expression evaluated and its resulting value then being used.

Comment: OK, then why does `"Fancy string - $('Hor"ray'.Replace('"', '"'+'"'))"` produce `Hor""ray`? Following your logic, the result should be `Hor"ray` as well.

Comment: Also in PHP `$code = '\"'; echo "(\") vs ($code)";` gives `(") vs (\")` which means that there is only one evaluation of `$code`. Otherwise it would output `(") vs (")`

Answer (score 0):

Could this not be done by simply using things like below:

```
`'$($RemFiles[$i].FullName)`'
`"$($RemFiles[$i].FullName)`"
```

Use the backtick and either a single or double quote to then prevent powershell from using this as an open comment, thus putting the actual symbol in...

The above outputs:

```
'F:\portable\adobe'

or

"F:\portable\adobe"
```

I noticed that it seems you are telling it to literally add two double quotes rather than just using the backtick to force it. Therefore telling it to add nothing surely :S So could you change this to something like this:

```
"Fancy string - $('Hor"ray'.Replace('"', '`"`"'))"
```

Though that may make 3, as you have one present in Hor"ray anyway.

Just got to test it, was busy with something:

```
PS D:\> "Fancy string - $('Hor"ray'.Replace('"', '`"`"'))"
Fancy string - Hor""ray
```

Scroll down on the site below to find out about the backtick and how/where it can be used.

> http://www.neolisk.com/techblog/powershell-specialcharactersandtokens