# Powershell reports MissingEndParenthesisInExpression even though the sub-expression is balanced

Tags: powershell

Here is my sub-expression:

```
    """$((($l -split " """)[1] -split """ ")[0])"""
```

I have checked and found no unpaired parentheses. However powershell insists in saying "Missing closing ')' in expression." 
Interestingly, the expression

```
    $((($l -split " """)[1] -split """ ")[0])
```

works fine.

Has anyone had similiar experience before? Is it a bug of Powershell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This.. is really interesting, and yes I would consider it a bug at least so far.

Here's a much simpler repro:

```
"$("`"")"
"$("""")"
```

It seems to be caused by using either form of double quote escaping (backtick or double double quote), inside a sub-expression, inside an expandable string.

It also appears that this is error comes right down to the parser itself:

```
$sb = @'
"$("`"")"
'@

$tokens = $null
$er = $null

$ast = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($sb, [ref]$tokens, [ref]$er)

$ast.EndBlock.Statements[0].PipelineElements[0].Expression.NestedExpressions

$tokens[0].NestedTokens
```

The nested tokens/expressions it finds just aren't correct.

I tested with Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell Core 6.0.0-rc.2 on WLS.

## Relevant Issues

- [Two double-quotes in inline expressions](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3039)
- [String in Sub-Expression incorrectly parsed](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4543)
- [Powershell: Doubled double quotes in inline expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24242338/3905079)

Comment: Thank you so much, @briantist. I suspected it, but you proved it so persuasively.