# How to convert $args to a string and execute?

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I'd like to pass all arguments that were given to the script and execute.

For example, given `execute.ps1` script:

```
Invoke-Expression $($args[0])
```

I can run:

```
.\execute.ps1 hostname
myhostname
```

Same with two parameters with this script:

```
Invoke-Expression "$($args[0]) $($args[1])"
```

and executing it by:

```
.\execute.ps1 echo foo
foo
```

**How I can make the script universal to support unknown number of arguments?**

For example:

```
.\execute.ps1 echo foo bar buzz ...
```

---

I've tried the following combinations which failed:

```
Invoke-Expression $args
```

> Invoke-Expression : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Command'. Specified method is not supported.

---

```
Invoke-Expression [system.String]::Join(" ", $args)
```

> Invoke-Expression : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.

---

```
Invoke-Expression $args.split(" ")
```

> Invoke-Expression : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Command'. Specified method is not supported.

---

```
Invoke-Expression [String] $args
```

> Invoke-Expression : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.

Comment: could you not just specify input parameters for your .ps1 file?

Comment: I need it dynamic and I don't know how many parameters there are. I've one use case when I've aws-ecr-login.ps1 which logins to different AWS role and executes docker commands. Then I'd like to allow user to pass arguments into the script, so it's invoked after the login process, but there could be unknown number of parameters. The use case doesn't really matters, therefore I've simplified the example as I could.

Comment: [I would caution against the use of `Invoke-Expression`.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recommend [Bill_Stewart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51545431/3905079) to avoid issues with the command itself (first argument) having spaces. But even with that answer, you would have to be careful to individual quote arguments, with the caveat that [that itself itself a complicated thing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/twistylittlepassagesallalike/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way).

---

You can just do:

```
 Invoke-Expression "$args"
```

By default converting to a string that way will join it with spaces (technically, join it with the default output field separator, which is the value of `$OFS`, which defaults to a space).

You can also do a manual join as in Wayne's answer.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart true, though neither will the other answers. This method of passing parameters will require the invoker to understand that PowerShell will interpret the first set of quotes, and repeat-quote as necessary `execute.ps1 echo '"hello there"'`. This is true of any shell really though, isn't it?

Comment: I don't recommend this answer because [`Invoke-Expression` is considered harmful](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I've updated my answer, but most of what's in that article isn't addressed by using `&` alone either; and of course the injection angle is only going to be addressed by not trying to execute arguments.

Answer (score 4):

$args is a whitespace delimited array of strings created from the imput

```
   Invoke-Expression -Command "$($args -join " ")"
```

Re-joining it with a whitespace character, and passing it to invoke-expression as a string works for me.

Comment: Could also be done manually a little more simply: `-Command ($args -join ' ')`

Comment: I tend to get a little "cast as string" happy in my scripts. I can never remember all of the rules of what works when ;)

Comment: Seems harmless to do a subexpression (any performance impact would be negligible unless it's a really big loop) , but [subexpressions have some bugs that you may never run into, but really suck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47877473/3905079) so I try to avoid them when they aren't needed.

Comment: If you have arrays in $args (e.g., one of parameters is 1,2,3), they are passed as the string "System.Object[]" because each item in $args is converted to string using ToString() before concatenation, and Array.ToString() loses data.

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation would be to avoid `Invoke-Expression` and use `&` instead. Example:

```
$command = $args[0]
$params = ""
if ( $args.Count -gt 1 ) {
  $params = $args[1..$($args.Count - 1)]
}
& $command $params
```

Of course, parameters containing spaces would still need to contain embedded quotes.

Comment: If `$command` is a function, it will receive just one parameter `$params` which is an array, instead of array of parameters as it expects. To avoid it, write the last line in this way: `& $command @params`

Comment: The question is about when the first element of the array is the command name and the subsequent elements are the arguments. (That's why my answer is written the way it is.)